# How can I make a discord bot create a role based on what the person types in the command

Tags: python, roles, discord

I am new to coding and making discord bots, I have gotten it to make a role using a command but I can't figure out how to make it make a role based on what the person puts in the command. For example, !rolecreate test, if I typed that I want it to make a role called test and give it to me. If it helps here is the code I have for just making a blue role called test.

https://pastebin.com/HMkLTkSe

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def rolecreate(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    await client.create_role(author.server, name='TEST', colour=discord.Colour(0x0000FF))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but something like this should work:

```
from discord.utils import get

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def rolecreate(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    # split the string to get the rolename to create
    role_name = ctx.message.content.lower().split("!rolecreate ", maxsplit=1)[1]
    # check if that role already exists
    check_for_duplicate = get(ctx.message.server.roles, name=role_name)
    if check_for_duplicate is not None: # if the role doesn't exist
        # create the role
        role = await client.create_role(author.server, name=role_name, colour=discord.Colour(0x0000FF))
        await client.add_roles(author, role)
    else:
        client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "That role already exists")
```